# How to position buttons according to background in Android?

Tags: button, background

I'm making an app that needs the following background. Trouble is, I'm not sure how to position the three buttons inside the circle.

[image: preview all screen sizes]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: @isherwood I tried centering the buttons and using padding, but it doesn't work for all aspect ratios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinearLayout(vertical), put all the buttons there and use the View subclass called Space, above, inbetween and below the buttons. Then adjust layout:weight until you get the desired proportion. Don't forget to set height to 0 for layout:weight to take effect.